# How to design a flash card App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am new to IOS 5 and I am interested in creating a flashcard app.  My question is would it be ideal to make the make the text dynamic  or use multiple images.  The app would have over 200 words.
I have created the flash card page but now I need to determine which is the best step.

Comment: ANKI could inspire you: http://ankisrs.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with a main menu that gives you a choice between creating a new "group" of cards and loading a previously created group.  The card itself should be easy: Title, body, backside text.  These cards can be saved in groups depending on their subject (e.x. Biology or Vocabulary for iPhones) and can then be accessed and flipped through by choosing the group.  Use a modalview animation to flip the card over, it is probably the easiest.